# Is it possible when multiplying two polynomials that, after the collection of similar (like) terms, all terms except one vanish?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am working with an 8th grader.

In their book, *Algebra*, Chen and Gelfand ask this problem:

> **Problem 97**. Is it possible when multiplying two polynomials that, after the collection of similar (like) terms, all terms except one vanish? (Do not count the case when each of the polynomials has only one monomial.)

A similar question (also from the same book) was [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233106/83821) a while ago.

I guess the answer to this one is similar to that one.

I tried to explain it by considering two polynomials $A: a_0 + a_1x$ and $B: b_0 + b_1x$ and then considering the cases where the product has only one term (either $a_0b_0$, $(a_0b_1 + a_1b_0)x$, or $a_1b_1x^2$) without making both $A$ and $B$ monomials or either of them the zero polynomial (that is at least three of $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1$ are nonzero). In each of the cases, we showed that it is impossible to do so.

Is our answer correct?

I guess the result can be generalized for polynomials in single variable (assuming that the answer is correct) using the standard form: $\displaystyle \sum_0^n a_ix^i \cdot \sum_0^m b_ix^i$.

Comment: It seems like you could make an argument based on the unique factorization of polynomials.  If the product is $ax^n$, then the factorization into irreducibles is $ax\cdot x\cdots x$ and so your original two factors have to be monomials.

Comment: Strictly speaking this depends on the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring) in which the coefficients live

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. Along the same lines we show the general case.

If $A$ is not a monomial then it can be written as $\sum_r^n a_ix^i$ with $0\leq r<n$, $a_r\not=0$ and $a_n\not=0$. Let $B=\sum_s^m b_ix^i$ with $0\leq s\leq m$, $b_s\not=0$ and $b_m\not=0$. Notice that $B$ is monomial when $m=s$.

The product $AB$ contains a unique monomial of maximum degree $a_nb_mx^{n+m}$ and a unique monomial of minimum degree $a_rb_sx^{r+s}$. Those two monomials are non-zero because $a_nb_m\not=0$, $a_rb_s\not=0$, and distinct because $r+s<n+m$. Therefore the product $AB$, after the collection of similar terms, has at least two terms.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two non-zero polynomials, $n>0$ and $m>0$ with real powers and coefficients, $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

Case 1: Single term in each polynomial
$$p(x)=a_1x^n$$
$$q(x)=b_1x^m$$

$$a_1.b_1x^{n+m}$$

That is a single term in the product.
Example: $p(x)=x^2$ and $q(x)=x$, the product is $x^3$.

Case 2: All other cases

$$p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$
$$q(x)=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_1x+b_0$$

When you perform the multiplication, we get a polynomial of degree $n+m$. We also get the tail constants multiplied by each other with nothing to cancel them (since all other terms are associated with x).

Accordingly, the product will always be of the form:

$a_n.b_m.x^{n+m} + a_0.b_0 + $[possibly other terms multiplied by different powers of $x$].

The "other terms multiplied by different powers of $x$" expression, may be zero during re-arrangement process but the the first two terms in the above will always stay. As a result, the product will always contain at least $2$ terms.

Example: $p(x)=x+3$ and $q(x)=x-3$, the product is $x^2-9$.

Comment: Yes. There may be a difference in the values of the coefficients and powers of course.